# Como agregar un listado de hijos a un componente React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objeto, component

Estoy realizando un árbol de categorías. Mi componente principal se llama "CatTrees" y es el encargado de listar todas las categorías "root", es decir, todas aquellas categorías que no poseen padre.

```js
const CatTrees = () => {
    
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getRootCats();
  }, [cats]);

  const getRootCats = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${URI}/root`);
    setCats(res.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-3">
      {cats.map((cat) => (
        <div className="container-nav-tree" key={cat.id}>
          <div className="nav-tree-item">
            <div className="nav-tree-item-name">
              <div className="toggleable" onClick={(e) => addNodes(e, cat.id)}>
                {" "}
              </div>
              <label>{cat.cat_name}</label>
              <div className="nav-tree-item-info follow-true">
                {cat.updatedAt}
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul className="nav-tree-item-toggler-info">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CatTrees;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Como pueden ver en el código, cada categoría adiciona un "onClick" que ejecuta la función "addNodes". Dicha función es la encargada de buscar en la DDBB las categorías que son hijas del padre que llama la función y las inserta en la lista HTML cuya clase es "nav-tree-item-toggler-info"

Dejo la función addNodes:

```js
const addNodes = async (e, id) => {
  const caller = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  const ulCaller = caller.childNodes[1];

  // limpiamos por si tenía algo
  ulCaller.textContent = "";

  // agregamos hijos
  ulCaller.classList.toggle("active");
  const writeNodes = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${URI}/nodes/${id}`);
    if (res.data.length === 0) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.textContent = "No existen subcategorías";
      console.log(li);
      return ulCaller.appendChild(li);
    } else {
      const childs = res.data.map((child) => {
        return (<NodeCat key={child.id} cat={child.id} />)
      });
      return ulCaller.append(childs);
    }
  };
  writeNodes();
};

export default addNodes;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Como es posible que cada categoría tenga dentro más subcategorías, pensé un componente que se llamara constantemente y una función genérica. Es por esta razón que la función antes detallada (addNodes) renderiza (en caso de tener hijos) el componente react NodeCat:

```js
const NodeCat = ({cat}) => {
  return (
    <div class="nav-tree-item">
      <div class="nav-tree-item-name">
        <div class="toggleable" onClick={(e) => addNodes(e, cat.id)}> </div>
        <label>
            {cat.cat_name}
        </label>
        <div class="nav-tree-item-info follow-false">
            {cat.updatedAt}
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-tree-item-toggler-info"></ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NodeCat;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

El problema que presento es que en el navegador se me está renderizando un "[objet, Objet]" de JS en vez de renderizarse el componente "NodeCat"

Alguna idea de como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Pues te sugeriría usar la lógica de react... si lo que quieres es pintar las subcategorías realmente lo que necesitas sería una variable state que contenga esas subcategorías al igual que haces con las categorías, y el map se va a ejecutar siempre y cuando el arreglo de subcategorías esté lleno, en este caso retornarías los li tal y como tienes en tu lógica actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al comentario que te agregué, te podría quedar algo como:

```
const CatTrees = () => {
    
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);
  const [subCats, setSubCats] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getRootCats();
  }, [cats]);

  const getRootCats = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${URI}/root`);
    setCats(res.data);
  };

  const getSubCats = async (e, id) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${URI}/nodes/${id}`);
    setSubCats(res);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-3">
      {cats.map((cat) => (
        <div className="container-nav-tree" key={cat.id}>
          <div className="nav-tree-item">
            <div className="nav-tree-item-name">
              <div className="toggleable" onClick={(e) => getSubCats(e, cat.id)}>
                {" "}
              </div>
              <label>{cat.cat_name}</label>
              <div className="nav-tree-item-info follow-true">
              {
                (subCats.length > 0) ? 
                subCats.map((subCat) => (<NodeCat key={subCat.id} cat={subCat.id}/>)) 
                : <li>No existen subCategorias</li>
                }
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul className="nav-tree-item-toggler-info">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Básicamente al seleccionar tu categoría vas a buscar las sub categorias, asignas el valor a tu variable de estado y en el render va a mostrar las sub categorías si es que encontró de lo contrario, va a mostrar la lista.

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias Alex por tu respuesta, fue muy útil el paso que hemos dado. El problema ahora es que en el array de subcats se va reemplazando constantemente el contenido, en función de si se va haciendo click en diferentes categorías, provocando un error en la visualización. 

A mi parecer deberíamos crear como un useState por cada categoría / subcategoría que se va renderizando, sería esto viable?

Comment: Desde el componente nodecat estoy repitiendo la función de getSubCats y me está funcionando bien, el problema es cuando switcheo entre categorías root. Te dejo un video para que puedas verlo mejor.
https://www.loom.com/share/2517295452474b9fa113c7bf49c9b898

Comment: Lo resolví creando un nuevo componente RootCat. De esta manera reutilizamos la lógica y renderizamos por un lado las root con useStates independientes y por otro lado las subcats con useStates independientes tmb.
Muchas gracias por tu aporte Alex, fue de gran ayuda.

Comment: Excelente Mariano, agrega tu solución como respuesta para que alguién mas que tenga este problema pueda tener tu solución de referencia. Un saludo!